# Simple authentication server

Tags: java, authentication, spring

Here's a simple authentication server. It's pretty basic but has the core functionality of sign-up and log-in handling. Your best bet is to simply run the `docker-compose` file

## Main

```java
package com.example.tokenservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TokenServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TokenServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.config;

import com.example.tokenservice.handler.TokenHandler;
import com.example.tokenservice.util.WebFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunctions;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;

@Configuration
public class RouterConfig {
    private final TokenHandler tokenHandler;

    public RouterConfig(TokenHandler tokenHandler) {
        this.tokenHandler = tokenHandler;
    }

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> signUpRoute() {
        return RouterFunctions.route()
                .POST("/signup", tokenHandler::signUp)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RouterFunction<ServerResponse> logInRoute() {
        return RouterFunctions.route()
                .POST("/login", tokenHandler::logIn)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public WebFilter authenticationExceptionToUnauthorizedFilter() {
        return WebFilterFactory.exceptionHandlingWebFilter(AuthenticationException.class, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebFilter duplicateKeyExceptionToConflictFilter() {
        return WebFilterFactory.exceptionHandlingWebFilter(DuplicateKeyException.class, HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.config;

import com.example.tokenservice.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.tokenservice.util.WebFilterFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ReactiveAuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.ReactiveUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public WebFilterChainProxy noSecurityWebFilterChainProxy() {
        return WebFilterFactory.noOpWebFilterChainProxy();
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService(UserRepository userRepository) {
        return username -> Mono.<UserDetails>justOrEmpty(userRepository.findByUsername(username))
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.error(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user: " + username)));
    }

    @Bean
    public ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager(ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                                                               PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager =
                new UserDetailsRepositoryReactiveAuthenticationManager(userDetailsService);
        authenticationManager.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
        return authenticationManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.data.constant;

import lombok.AccessLevel;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;

@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
public class JWT {
    public static String ROLES = "roles";
    public static String KEY = "jxgEQeXHuPq8VdbyYFNkANdudQ53YUn4";
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.data.dto;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;

@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Setter
@Getter
@Builder
public class UserDto {
    private String username;
    private String password;
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.data.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;

import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role implements GrantedAuthority {
    public static final String USER = "user";
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String authority;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "authorities")
    private Set<User> users = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    public Role(String authority) {
        this.authority = authority;
    }

    public void addUser(User user) {
        users.add(user);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Role role = (Role) o;
        return authority.equals(role.authority);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(authority);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return authority;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.data.entity;

import jakarta.persistence.Column;
import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinColumn;
import jakarta.persistence.JoinTable;
import jakarta.persistence.ManyToMany;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "users")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    private UUID id;
    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String username;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String password;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Boolean enabled = true;
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "users_roles",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> authorities = ConcurrentHashMap.newKeySet();

    public void addRole(Role role) {
        authorities.add(role);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return enabled;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        User user = (User) o;
        return username.equals(user.username);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(username);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return MessageFormat.format("User[username={0}]", username);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.handler;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.dto.UserDto;
import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.User;
import com.example.tokenservice.mapper.UserMapper;
import com.example.tokenservice.service.token.TokenService;
import com.example.tokenservice.service.user.UserService;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ReactiveAuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Component
public class BasicTokenHandler implements TokenHandler {
    private final UserService userService;
    private final TokenService tokenService;
    private final ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    private final UserMapper userMapper;

    public BasicTokenHandler(UserService userService,
                             TokenService tokenService,
                             ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager,
                             UserMapper userMapper) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.tokenService = tokenService;
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        this.userMapper = userMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<ServerResponse> signUp(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(UserDto.class)
                .map(userMapper::toUser)
                .map(userService::encodePassword)
                .map(userService::addDefaultRoles)
                .map(userService::save)
                .map(this::toAuthenticatedUpat)
                .map(tokenService::generateTokenFor)
                .transform(jwt -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.CREATED).body(jwt, String.class));
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken toAuthenticatedUpat(User user) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.authenticated(
                user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<ServerResponse> logIn(ServerRequest request) {
        return request.bodyToMono(UserDto.class)
                .map(this::toUnauthenticatedUpat)
                .flatMap(authenticationManager::authenticate)
                .map(tokenService::generateTokenFor)
                .transform(jwt -> ServerResponse.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(jwt, String.class));
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken toUnauthenticatedUpat(UserDto userDto) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(
                userDto.getUsername(), userDto.getPassword());
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.handler;

import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public interface TokenHandler {
    Mono<ServerResponse> signUp(ServerRequest request);

    Mono<ServerResponse> logIn(ServerRequest request);
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.mapper;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.dto.UserDto;
import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.User;
import org.mapstruct.Mapper;

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface UserMapper {
    User toUser(UserDto userDto);
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.repository;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.Role;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.EntityGraph;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

public interface RoleRepository extends Repository<Role, UUID> {
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "users")
    Optional<Role> findByAuthority(String authority);

    Role save(Role role);
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.repository;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.EntityGraph;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

public interface UserRepository extends Repository<User, UUID> {
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "authorities")
    User save(User user);

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "authorities")
    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);

    Boolean existsByUsername(String username);
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.service.role;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.Role;
import com.example.tokenservice.repository.RoleRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class BasicRoleService implements RoleService {
    private final RoleRepository roleRepository;

    public BasicRoleService(RoleRepository roleRepository) {
        this.roleRepository = roleRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<Role> findByAuthority(String authority) {
        return roleRepository.findByAuthority(authority);
    }

    @Override
    public Role save(Role role) {
        return roleRepository.save(role);
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.service.role;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.Role;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface RoleService {
    Optional<Role> findByAuthority(String authority);

    Role save(Role authority);
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.service.token;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.constant.JWT;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.sql.Date;
import java.time.DayOfWeek;
import java.time.LocalDate;

@Service
public class JwtTokenService implements TokenService {
    @Override
    public String generateTokenFor(Authentication authentication) {
        return Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(authentication.getName())
                .claim(JWT.ROLES, authentication.getAuthorities()
                        .stream()
                        .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                        .toList())
                .setExpiration(Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()
                        .plusDays(DayOfWeek.values().length)))
                .signWith(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(JWT.KEY.getBytes()))
                .compact();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.service.token;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;

public interface TokenService {
    String generateTokenFor(Authentication authentication);
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.service.user;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.Role;
import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.User;
import com.example.tokenservice.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.tokenservice.service.role.RoleService;
import org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class BasicUserService implements UserService {
    private final UserRepository userRepository;
    private final RoleService roleService;
    private final PasswordEncoder encoder;

    public BasicUserService(UserRepository userRepository,
                            RoleService roleService,
                            PasswordEncoder encoder) {
        this.userRepository = userRepository;
        this.roleService = roleService;
        this.encoder = encoder;
    }

    @Override
    public User save(User user) {
        if (userRepository.existsByUsername(user.getUsername()))
            throw new DuplicateKeyException("Username already taken: " + user.getUsername());
        return userRepository.save(user);
    }

    @Override
    public User encodePassword(User user) {
        String encodedPassword = encoder.encode(user.getPassword());
        user.setPassword(encodedPassword);
        return user;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public User addDefaultRoles(User user) {
        Optional<Role> userRoleOptional = roleService.findByAuthority(Role.USER);
        Role userRole = userRoleOptional.orElseGet(() -> roleService.save(new Role(Role.USER)));
        userRole.addUser(user);
        user.addRole(userRole);
        return user;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.service.user;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.User;

public interface UserService {
    User save(User user);

    User encodePassword(User user);

    User addDefaultRoles(User user);
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.util;

import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBuffer;
import org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DefaultDataBufferFactory;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.MatcherSecurityWebFilterChain;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.util.matcher.ServerWebExchangeMatcher;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Function;

public class WebFilterFactory {
    private WebFilterFactory() {
    }

    public static WebFilter noOpWebFilter() {
        return (exchange, chain) -> chain.filter(exchange);
    }

    public static WebFilterChainProxy noOpWebFilterChainProxy() {
        return new WebFilterChainProxy(
                new MatcherSecurityWebFilterChain(
                        exchange -> ServerWebExchangeMatcher.MatchResult.match(),
                        List.of(noOpWebFilter())
                ));
    }

    public static WebFilter exceptionHandlingWebFilter(Class<? extends Throwable> throwableClass,
                                                       HttpStatus status) {
        return exceptionHandlingWebFilter(throwableClass, status, Throwable::getMessage);
    }

    public static <T extends Throwable> WebFilter exceptionHandlingWebFilter(Class<T> throwableClass,
                                                                             HttpStatus status,
                                                                             Function<T, String> responseBodyValueFunction) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> chain.filter(exchange)
                .onErrorResume(throwableClass,
                        t -> setResponse(exchange, status, responseBodyValueFunction.apply(t)));
    }

    private static Mono<Void> setResponse(ServerWebExchange exchange,
                                          HttpStatus status,
                                          String responseBody) {
        ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getResponse();
        response.setStatusCode(status);
        DataBuffer dataBuffer = DefaultDataBufferFactory.sharedInstance
                .wrap(responseBody.getBytes());
        return response.writeWith(Mono.just(dataBuffer));
    }
}
```

```yml
# application.yml

server:
  port: 8100

logging:
  level:
    root: ${ROOT_LOGGING_LEVEL:info}

spring:
  datasource:
    username: ${POSTGRES_USERNAME:postgres}
    password: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD:postgres}
    url: ${POSTGRES_URL:jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres}
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: create-drop
    show-sql: true
  application:
    name: token-service

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: ${EUREKA_URL:http://localhost:8761/eureka}
```

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--suppress VulnerableLibrariesLocal -->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>token-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>token-service</name>
    <description>token-service</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
        <jsonwebtoken.version>0.11.5</jsonwebtoken.version>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.5.Final</mapstruct.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-impl</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>${jsonwebtoken.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.projectreactor</groupId>
            <artifactId>reactor-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>
<!--                        <path>-->
<!--                            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>-->
<!--                            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>-->
<!--                            <version>2.6.6</version>-->
<!--                        </path>-->
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <arg>
                            -Amapstruct.defaultComponentModel=spring
                        </arg>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

## Tests

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.config;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.Role;
import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.User;
import com.example.tokenservice.testUtil.UserUtil;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AccountStatusException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ReactiveAuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.ReactiveUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class AuthenticationManagerTest {
    SecurityConfig securityConfig = new SecurityConfig();
    @Mock
    ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    @Mock
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        authenticationManager = securityConfig.authenticationManager(userDetailsService, passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Test
    void testAuthenticate_withNonExistentUser_throws() {
        String nonExistentUsername = "mystery-man";

        given(userDetailsService.findByUsername(nonExistentUsername))
                .willReturn(Mono.error(new UsernameNotFoundException("No such user")));

        Authentication authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(nonExistentUsername, null);

        StepVerifier.create(authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication))
                .expectError(UsernameNotFoundException.class)
                .verify();
    }

    @Test
    void testAuthenticate_withExistingUser_butInvalidCredentials_stillThrows() {
        String realPassword = "real_password";

        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("minnie_m");
        user.setPassword(realPassword);

        given(userDetailsService.findByUsername(user.getUsername()))
                .willReturn(Mono.just(user));

        String fakePassword = "fake_password";
        given(passwordEncoder.matches(fakePassword, realPassword)).willReturn(false);

        Authentication authentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(user.getUsername(), fakePassword);

        StepVerifier.create(authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication))
                .expectError(AuthenticationException.class)
                .verify();
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("accountInvalidators")
    void testAuthenticate_withExistingUser_butIllegalAccountState_throws(Consumer<User> accountInvalidator) {
        String realPassword = "real_password";

        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("minnie_m");
        user.setPassword(realPassword);

        String encodedPassword = "#nc0ded_pa$$word";
        List<Role> someRoles = Stream.of("role", "another_role")
                .map(Role::new).toList();
        given(userDetailsService.findByUsername(user.getUsername())).willReturn(Mono.just(
                UserUtil.cloneAndMutate(user, u -> {
                    u.setPassword(encodedPassword);
                    someRoles.forEach(u::addRole);
                    accountInvalidator.accept(u);
                }))
        );

        Authentication authentication =
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        StepVerifier.create(authenticationManager.authenticate(authentication))
                .expectError(AccountStatusException.class)
                .verify();
    }

    static List<Consumer<User>> accountInvalidators() {
        return List.of(
                u -> u.setEnabled(false)
        );
    }

    @Test
    void testAuthenticate_withExistingUser_withValidCredentials_authenticates() {
        String realPassword = "real_password";

        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("minnie_m");
        user.setPassword(realPassword);

        String encodedPassword = "#nc0ded_pa$$word";
        List<Role> someRoles = Stream.of("role", "another_role")
                .map(Role::new).toList();
        given(userDetailsService.findByUsername(user.getUsername())).willReturn(Mono.just(
                UserUtil.cloneAndMutate(user, u -> {
                    u.setPassword(encodedPassword);
                    someRoles.forEach(u::addRole);
                }))
        );

        given(passwordEncoder.matches(realPassword, encodedPassword)).willReturn(true);

        Authentication expectedAuthentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.authenticated(
                user, encodedPassword, someRoles
        );

        Authentication passedAuthentication =
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        StepVerifier.create(authenticationManager.authenticate(passedAuthentication))
                .expectNext(expectedAuthentication)
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.config;

import com.example.tokenservice.handler.TokenHandler;
import com.example.tokenservice.testUtil.ServerResponseUtil;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.ParameterizedTest;
import org.junit.jupiter.params.provider.MethodSource;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.mock.http.server.reactive.MockServerHttpRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.reactive.function.server.MockServerRequest;
import org.springframework.mock.web.server.MockServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.RouterFunction;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerRequest;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class RouterFunctionTest {
    @Mock
    TokenHandler tokenHandler;
    @InjectMocks
    RouterConfig routerConfig;

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("nonMatchingSignupRequests")
    void signUpRoute_withWithNonMatchingRequests(ServerRequest nonMatchingRequest) {
        RouterFunction<ServerResponse> signUpRoute = routerConfig.signUpRoute();
        StepVerifier.create(signUpRoute.route(nonMatchingRequest))
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    static List<ServerRequest> nonMatchingSignupRequests() {
        return List.of(
                MockServerRequest.builder()
                        .method(HttpMethod.DELETE)
                        .uri(URI.create("/signup"))
                        .exchange(MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.delete("/signup")))
                        .build(),
                MockServerRequest.builder()
                        .method(HttpMethod.POST)
                        .uri(URI.create("/wrong-signup"))
                        .exchange(MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.post("/wrong-signup")))
                        .build()
        );
    }

    @Test
    void signUpRoute_withMatchingRequest() {
        ServerRequest matchingRequest = MockServerRequest.builder()
                .method(HttpMethod.POST)
                .uri(URI.create("/signup"))
                .exchange(MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.post("/signup")))
                .build();

        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.CREATED;
        String bodyValue = "j.w.token";
        Mono<ServerResponse> response = ServerResponse.status(status)
                .body(Mono.just(bodyValue), String.class);
        given(tokenHandler.signUp(matchingRequest)).willReturn(response);

        RouterFunction<ServerResponse> signUpRoute = routerConfig.signUpRoute();
        StepVerifier.create(signUpRoute.route(matchingRequest))
                .assertNext(handlerFunction -> StepVerifier.create(handlerFunction.handle(matchingRequest))
                        .assertNext(r -> ServerResponseUtil.responseChecksOut(r, status, bodyValue))
                        .verifyComplete())
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @MethodSource("nonMatchingLoginRequests")
    void testLogInRoute_withWithNonMatchingRequests(ServerRequest nonMatchingRequest) {
        RouterFunction<ServerResponse> signUpRoute = routerConfig.logInRoute();
        StepVerifier.create(signUpRoute.route(nonMatchingRequest))
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    static List<ServerRequest> nonMatchingLoginRequests() {
        return List.of(
                MockServerRequest.builder()
                        .method(HttpMethod.DELETE)
                        .uri(URI.create("/login"))
                        .exchange(MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.delete("/login")))
                        .build(),
                MockServerRequest.builder()
                        .method(HttpMethod.POST)
                        .uri(URI.create("/wrong-login"))
                        .exchange(MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.post("/wrong-login")))
                        .build()
        );
    }

    @Test
    void testLogInRoute_withMatchingRequest() {
        ServerRequest matchingRequest = MockServerRequest.builder()
                .method(HttpMethod.POST)
                .uri(URI.create("/login"))
                .exchange(MockServerWebExchange.from(MockServerHttpRequest.post("/login")))
                .build();

        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.OK;
        String bodyValue = "j.w.token";
        Mono<ServerResponse> response = ServerResponse.status(status)
                .body(Mono.just(bodyValue), String.class);
        given(tokenHandler.logIn(matchingRequest)).willReturn(response);

        RouterFunction<ServerResponse> signUpRoute = routerConfig.logInRoute();
        StepVerifier.create(signUpRoute.route(matchingRequest))
                .assertNext(handlerFunction -> StepVerifier.create(handlerFunction.handle(matchingRequest))
                        .assertNext(r -> ServerResponseUtil.responseChecksOut(r, status, bodyValue))
                        .verifyComplete())
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.config;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.User;
import com.example.tokenservice.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.tokenservice.testUtil.UserUtil;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.ReactiveUserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import java.util.Optional;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class UserDetailsServiceTest {
    SecurityConfig securityConfig = new SecurityConfig();
    @Mock
    UserRepository userRepository;
    ReactiveUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        userDetailsService = securityConfig.userDetailsService(userRepository);
    }

    @Test
    void testUserDetailsService_ifUserFetched_returnsItBack() {
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername("scrooge_m");
        user.setPassword("password");

        given(userRepository.findByUsername(user.getUsername())).willReturn(Optional.of(user));

        StepVerifier.create(userDetailsService.findByUsername(user.getUsername()))
                .expectNextMatches(u -> UserUtil.haveEqualFields(u, user))
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    @Test
    void testUserDetailsService_ifUserNotFetched_throwsUserNotFoundException() {
        String unknownUsername = "Unknown_user";

        given(userRepository.findByUsername(unknownUsername)).willReturn(Optional.empty());

        StepVerifier.create(userDetailsService.findByUsername(unknownUsername))
                .expectError(UsernameNotFoundException.class)
                .verify();
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.handler;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.dto.UserDto;
import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.Role;
import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.User;
import com.example.tokenservice.mapper.UserMapper;
import com.example.tokenservice.service.token.TokenService;
import com.example.tokenservice.service.user.UserService;
import com.example.tokenservice.testUtil.ServerResponseUtil;
import com.example.tokenservice.testUtil.UserUtil;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.mock.web.reactive.function.server.MockServerRequest;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.ReactiveAuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import java.net.URI;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;

import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class BasicTokenHandlerTest {
    @Mock
    UserService userService;
    @Mock
    TokenService tokenService;
    @Mock
    ReactiveAuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Mock
    UserMapper userMapper;
    @InjectMocks
    BasicTokenHandler tokenHandler;

    @Test
    void testSignUp() {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        userDto.setUsername("goofus_d");
        userDto.setPassword("12345");

        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(userDto.getUsername());
        user.setPassword(userDto.getPassword());

        given(userMapper.toUser(userDto)).willReturn(user);

        User userAfterPasswordEncoding = UserUtil.cloneAndMutate(user, u -> u.setPassword("encoded_pass"));
        given(userService.encodePassword(user)).willReturn(userAfterPasswordEncoding);

        User userWithDefaultRoles = UserUtil.cloneAndMutate(userAfterPasswordEncoding, u -> u.addRole(new Role(Role.USER)));
        given(userService.addDefaultRoles(userAfterPasswordEncoding)).willReturn(userWithDefaultRoles);

        UUID assignedId = UUID.randomUUID();
        User persistedUser = UserUtil.cloneAndMutate(userWithDefaultRoles, u -> u.setId(assignedId));
        given(userService.save(userWithDefaultRoles)).willReturn(persistedUser);

        String jwt = "just.imagine.its.a.JWT";
        given(tokenService.generateTokenFor(toAuthenticatedUpat(persistedUser))).willReturn(jwt);

        MockServerRequest request = MockServerRequest.builder()
                .method(HttpMethod.POST)
                .uri(URI.create("/signup"))
                .body(Mono.just(userDto));

        StepVerifier.create(tokenHandler.signUp(request))
                .assertNext(response -> ServerResponseUtil.responseChecksOut(response, HttpStatus.CREATED, jwt))
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken toAuthenticatedUpat(User user) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.authenticated(
                user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), user.getAuthorities());
    }

    @Test
    void testLogIn() {
        UserDto userDto = new UserDto();
        userDto.setUsername("goofus_d");
        userDto.setPassword("12345");

        Authentication passedAuthentication = toUnauthenticatedUpat(userDto);
        Authentication returnedAuthentication = UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.authenticated(
                userDto, userDto.getUsername(), List.of(new Role("some_default_role")
                ));
        given(authenticationManager.authenticate(passedAuthentication)).willReturn(Mono.just(returnedAuthentication));

        String jwt = "json.web.token";
        given(tokenService.generateTokenFor(returnedAuthentication)).willReturn(jwt);

        MockServerRequest request = MockServerRequest.builder()
                .method(HttpMethod.POST)
                .uri(URI.create("/login"))
                .body(Mono.just(userDto));

        StepVerifier.create(tokenHandler.logIn(request))
                .assertNext(response -> ServerResponseUtil.responseChecksOut(response, HttpStatus.OK, jwt))
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken toUnauthenticatedUpat(UserDto userDto) {
        return UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.unauthenticated(userDto.getUsername(), userDto.getPassword());
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.mapper;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.dto.UserDto;
import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.User;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mapstruct.factory.Mappers;

import static org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions.assertSoftly;

class UserMapperTest {
    UserMapper mapper = Mappers.getMapper(UserMapper.class);

    @Test
    void testToUser() {
        String username = "mickey_m", password = "pass";
        UserDto userDto = UserDto.builder().username(username).password(password).build();
        User user = mapper.toUser(userDto);
        assertSoftly(soft -> {
            soft.assertThat(user.getUsername()).isEqualTo(username);
            soft.assertThat(user.getPassword()).isEqualTo(password);
        });
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.service.role;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.Role;
import com.example.tokenservice.repository.RoleRepository;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.UUID;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions.assertSoftly;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class BasicRoleServiceTest {
    @Mock
    RoleRepository roleRepository;
    @InjectMocks
    BasicRoleService roleService;

    @Test
    void testFindByAuthority() {
        Role role = new Role(Role.USER);
        role.setId(UUID.randomUUID());

        given(roleRepository.findByAuthority(Role.USER)).willReturn(Optional.of(role));

        Optional<Role> roleOptional = roleService.findByAuthority(Role.USER);

        assertThat(roleOptional).isPresent();
        assertSoftly(soft -> {
            soft.assertThat(roleOptional.get())
                    .extracting(Role::getId)
                    .isEqualTo(role.getId());
            soft.assertThat(roleOptional.get())
                    .extracting(Role::getAuthority)
                    .isEqualTo(role.getAuthority());
        });
    }

    @Test
    void testSave() {
        Role role = new Role(Role.USER);

        Role persistedRole = new Role();
        persistedRole.setAuthority(role.getAuthority());
        persistedRole.setId(UUID.randomUUID());

        given(roleRepository.save(role)).willReturn(persistedRole);

        Role returnedRole = roleService.save(role);

        assertSoftly(soft -> {
            soft.assertThat(returnedRole)
                    .extracting(Role::getId)
                    .isEqualTo(persistedRole.getId());
            soft.assertThat(returnedRole)
                    .extracting(Role::getAuthority)
                    .isEqualTo(persistedRole.getAuthority());
        });
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.service.token;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.constant.JWT;
import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.Role;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.TestingAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;

import java.util.List;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

class JwtTokenServiceTest {
    TokenService tokenService = new JwtTokenService();

    @Test
    void testGenerateTokenFor() {
        String principal = "daisy_d";
        List<GrantedAuthority> roles = List.of(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(Role.USER));
        TestingAuthenticationToken authentication = new TestingAuthenticationToken(principal, null, roles);

        String jwt = tokenService.generateTokenFor(authentication);

        Claims jwtClaims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                .setSigningKey(Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(JWT.KEY.getBytes()))
                .build()
                .parseClaimsJws(jwt)
                .getBody();

        assertThat(jwtClaims.getSubject()).isEqualTo(principal);
        assertThat(jwtClaims.get(JWT.ROLES))
                .extracting(List.class::cast)
                .asList()
                .containsExactlyInAnyOrderElementsOf(roles.stream()
                        .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority)
                        .toList());
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.service.user;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.Role;
import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.User;
import com.example.tokenservice.repository.UserRepository;
import com.example.tokenservice.service.role.RoleService;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.InjectMocks;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;

import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThatThrownBy;
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assumptions.assumeThat;
import static org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions.assertSoftly;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.then;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.never;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class BasicUserServiceTest {
    @Mock
    UserRepository userRepository;
    @Mock
    RoleService roleService;
    @Mock
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    @InjectMocks
    BasicUserService userService;

    @Test
    void testSave_withOccupiedUsername() {
        String occupiedUsername = "some_occupied_username";
        given(userRepository.existsByUsername(occupiedUsername)).willReturn(true);

        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(occupiedUsername);

        assertThatThrownBy(() -> userService.save(user)).isInstanceOf(DuplicateKeyException.class);
        then(userRepository).should(never()).save(any());
    }

    @Test
    void testSave_withVacantUsername() {
        String someVacantUsername = "some_vacant_username";
        given(userRepository.existsByUsername(someVacantUsername)).willReturn(false);

        User userToSave = new User();
        userToSave.setUsername(someVacantUsername);

        User persistedUser = new User();
        persistedUser.setUsername(userToSave.getUsername());
        persistedUser.setId(UUID.randomUUID());

        given(userRepository.save(userToSave)).willReturn(persistedUser);

        User returnedUser = userService.save(userToSave);

        then(userRepository).should().save(userToSave);

        assertThat(returnedUser).isEqualTo(persistedUser);
    }

    @Test
    void testEncodePassword() {
        String password = "password", username = "donald_d";
        User user = new User();
        user.setPassword(password);
        user.setUsername(username);

        String encodedPassword = "drowssap";
        given(passwordEncoder.encode(password)).willReturn(encodedPassword);

        User userWithEncodedPassword = userService.encodePassword(user);

        assertThat(userWithEncodedPassword).extracting(User::getPassword).isEqualTo(encodedPassword);
        assertThat(userWithEncodedPassword).extracting(User::getUsername).isEqualTo(username);
    }

    @Test
    void testAddDefaultRoles_ifDefaultRoleAbsent_persistsOne_thenAddsToUser() {
        User user = new User();
        assumeThat(user.getAuthorities()).isNullOrEmpty();

        given(roleService.findByAuthority(Role.USER)).willReturn(Optional.empty());

        Role defaultRole = new Role(Role.USER);
        given(roleService.save(defaultRole)).willAnswer(i -> {
            Role persistedRole = new Role(Role.USER);
            persistedRole.setId(UUID.randomUUID());
            return persistedRole;
        });

        User userWithDefaultRoles = userService.addDefaultRoles(user);

        then(roleService).should().save(defaultRole);

        Set<Role> userAuthorities = userWithDefaultRoles.getAuthorities();
        assertThat(userAuthorities).hasSize(1);
        Role roleInReturnedUser = userAuthorities.iterator().next();
        assertSoftly(soft -> {
            soft.assertThat(roleInReturnedUser.getAuthority()).isEqualTo(defaultRole.getAuthority());
            soft.assertThat(roleInReturnedUser.getId()).isNotNull();
            soft.assertThat(roleInReturnedUser.getUsers()).contains(user);
        });
    }

    @Test
    void testAddDefaultRoles_ifDefaultRoleAlreadyPersisted_addsFetchedRoleToUser() {
        User user = new User();
        assumeThat(user.getAuthorities()).isNullOrEmpty();

        Role role = new Role(Role.USER);
        role.setId(UUID.randomUUID());

        given(roleService.findByAuthority(Role.USER)).willReturn(Optional.of(role));

        User userWithDefaultRoles = userService.addDefaultRoles(user);

        then(roleService).should(never()).save(any());

        Set<Role> userAuthorities = userWithDefaultRoles.getAuthorities();
        assertThat(userAuthorities).hasSize(1);
        Role roleInReturnedUser = userAuthorities.iterator().next();
        assertSoftly(soft -> {
            soft.assertThat(roleInReturnedUser.getAuthority()).isEqualTo(role.getAuthority());
            soft.assertThat(roleInReturnedUser.getId()).isEqualTo(role.getId());
            soft.assertThat(roleInReturnedUser.getUsers()).contains(user);
        });
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.testUtil;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;
import org.springframework.web.reactive.function.server.ServerResponse;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import static org.assertj.core.api.SoftAssertions.assertSoftly;

public class ServerResponseUtil {
    @SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "DataFlowIssue"})
    public static <T> void responseChecksOut(ServerResponse response, HttpStatus expectedStatus, T expectedBody) {
        assertSoftly(soft -> {
            soft.assertThat(response.statusCode()).isEqualTo(expectedStatus);

            Mono<T> body = (Mono<T>) ReflectionTestUtils.getField(response, "entity");
            StepVerifier.create(body)
                    .expectNext(expectedBody)
                    .verifyComplete();
        });
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.testUtil;

import com.example.tokenservice.data.entity.User;
import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.function.Consumer;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class UserUtil {
    private UserUtil() {
    }

    public static User cloneAndMutate(User user, Consumer<User> mutator) {
        User userCopy = clone(user);
        mutator.accept(userCopy);
        return userCopy;
    }

    public static User clone(User user) {
        User userCopy = new User();
        userCopy.setUsername(user.getUsername());
        userCopy.setPassword(user.getPassword());
        userCopy.setId(user.getId());
        userCopy.setEnabled(user.getEnabled());
        userCopy.setAuthorities(user.getAuthorities()
                .stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ConcurrentHashMap::newKeySet)));
        return userCopy;
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    public static <T extends UserDetails> boolean haveEqualFields(T oneUser, T anotherUser) {
        Field[] oneUserFields = oneUser.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        Field[] anotherUserFields = anotherUser.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (int i = 0; i < oneUserFields.length; i++) {
            Field oneUserField = oneUserFields[i];
            oneUserField.setAccessible(true);

            Field anotherUserField = anotherUserFields[i];
            anotherUserField.setAccessible(true);

            boolean areFieldsEqual = Objects.equals(oneUserField.get(oneUser), anotherUserField.get(anotherUser));

            if (!areFieldsEqual) return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

```java
package com.example.tokenservice.util;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.extension.ExtendWith;
import org.mockito.ArgumentCaptor;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.jupiter.MockitoExtension;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.server.reactive.ServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.mock.http.server.reactive.MockServerHttpResponse;
import org.springframework.security.web.server.WebFilterChainProxy;
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter;
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;
import reactor.test.StepVerifier;

import java.text.MessageFormat;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import static org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.any;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.given;
import static org.mockito.BDDMockito.then;

@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class WebFilterFactoryTest {
    @Mock
    private ServerWebExchange exchange;
    @Mock
    private WebFilterChain chain;

    @Test
    void noOpWebFilter() {
        given(chain.filter(any())).willReturn(Mono.empty());

        WebFilter noOpWebFilter = WebFilterFactory.noOpWebFilter();
        StepVerifier.create(noOpWebFilter.filter(exchange, chain))
                .verifyComplete();

        then(chain).should().filter(exchange);
        then(chain).shouldHaveNoMoreInteractions();
        then(exchange).shouldHaveNoInteractions();
    }

    @Test
    void noOpWebFilterChainProxy() {
        given(chain.filter(any())).willReturn(Mono.empty());

        WebFilterChainProxy filterChainProxy = WebFilterFactory.noOpWebFilterChainProxy();
        StepVerifier.create(filterChainProxy.filter(exchange, chain))
                .verifyComplete();

        then(chain).should().filter(exchange);
        then(chain).shouldHaveNoMoreInteractions();
        then(exchange).shouldHaveNoInteractions();
    }

    @Test
    void testExceptionHandlingWebFilter_withDefaultBodyMapping() {
        String exceptionMessage = "Something happened!";
        given(chain.filter(exchange)).willReturn(Mono.error(new SomeException(exceptionMessage)));

        given(exchange.getResponse()).willReturn(new MockServerHttpResponse());

        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT;
        WebFilter webFilter =
                WebFilterFactory.exceptionHandlingWebFilter(SomeException.class, status);

        StepVerifier.create(webFilter.filter(exchange, chain))
                .verifyComplete();

        ArgumentCaptor<ServerWebExchange> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ServerWebExchange.class);

        then(chain).should().filter(captor.capture());

        ServerWebExchange newExchange = captor.getValue();
        assertThat(newExchange).extracting(ServerWebExchange::getResponse)
                .extracting(ServerHttpResponse::getStatusCode)
                .isEqualTo(status);

        StepVerifier.create(((MockServerHttpResponse) exchange.getResponse()).getBodyAsString())
                .expectNext(exceptionMessage)
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    @Test
    void testExceptionHandlingWebFilter_withCustomBodyMapping() {
        Throwable exceptionCause = new UnknownError("Nobody knows what happened");
        Throwable exception = new SomeException("Something happened!", exceptionCause);
        given(chain.filter(exchange)).willReturn(Mono.error(exception));

        given(exchange.getResponse()).willReturn(new MockServerHttpResponse());

        HttpStatus status = HttpStatus.I_AM_A_TEAPOT;

        WebFilter webFilter = WebFilterFactory.exceptionHandlingWebFilter(SomeException.class,
                status, t -> MessageFormat.format(
                        "This happened: {0}[{1}]. It was caused by: {2}[{3}]",
                        t.getClass().getSimpleName(), t.getMessage(),
                        t.getCause().getClass().getSimpleName(), t.getCause().getMessage()
                ));

        StepVerifier.create(webFilter.filter(exchange, chain))
                .verifyComplete();

        ArgumentCaptor<ServerWebExchange> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(ServerWebExchange.class);

        then(chain).should().filter(captor.capture());

        ServerWebExchange newExchange = captor.getValue();
        assertThat(newExchange).extracting(ServerWebExchange::getResponse)
                .extracting(ServerHttpResponse::getStatusCode)
                .isEqualTo(status);

        StepVerifier.create(((MockServerHttpResponse) exchange.getResponse()).getBodyAsString())
                .expectNext(MessageFormat.format(
                        "This happened: {0}[{1}]. It was caused by: {2}[{3}]",
                        exception.getClass().getSimpleName(), exception.getMessage(),
                        exceptionCause.getClass().getSimpleName(), exceptionCause.getMessage()
                ))
                .verifyComplete();
    }

    static class SomeException extends RuntimeException {
        public SomeException(String exceptionMessage) {
            super(exceptionMessage);
        }

        public SomeException(String exceptionMessage, Throwable cause) {
            super(exceptionMessage, cause);
        }
    }
}
```

## Docker

```yml
# docker-compose.yml

version: '2.1'

services:
  token-service:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8100:8100"
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy
      eureka:
        condition: service_healthy
    environment:
      POSTGRES_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      EUREKA_URL: http://eureka:8761/eureka

  db:
    image: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10

  eureka:
    image: nadchel/eureka-server:1.0
    ports:
      - "8761:8761"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://eureka:8761"]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 10s
      retries: 10
```

```
# Dockerfile

FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk AS builder

WORKDIR /app

COPY . .

RUN apk add --no-cache maven && \
    mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true

FROM amazoncorretto:17-alpine-jdk

WORKDIR /app

COPY --from=builder /app/target/token-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar .

EXPOSE 8100

CMD ["java", "-jar", "token-service-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Comment: My considerations:

Comment: **1.** Should my server prepend the `bearer` scheme prefix to JWT tokens? It doesn't. In truth, I just winged it, I don't know for sure how it's supposed to be done

Comment: **2.** An extra IO operation on each successful sign-up to check if a preferred username is already occupied. Not good. On the other hand, it's not that simple to avoid it (if at all possible) without dramatically decreasing information value of my responses *or* getting coupled with a RDBMS-specific types (more on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78054404/how-do-i-assert-on-a-serverresponse-body))

Comment: **3.** You may wonder why fetching a role eagerly fetches all users. It's because in my specific usage I need that associated `User` collection to add a new `User` (and I want to spare a query). It may be a bit inefficient if at some point that method is used under different circumstances. Again, it's [not that simple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78052519/what-liberties-am-i-granted-by-spring-data-in-terms-of-repository-method-naming)

Comment: **4.** IntelliJ gives me weak warnings for my long map chain in `signUp()`. Is it really bad?

Comment: **5.** I couldn't find a good way to assert on `ServerResponse`s in my tests so I reflectively fetch a non-public field by name (see `ServerResponseUtil`). I know the class and the field thanks to the IDE debugger. Again, I realize it's not perfect, but I couldn't find a better way

Comment: I know the character limit has been reached, however when adding additional information you should [edit] your question  instead of adding a comment. Learn more about comments including when to comment and when not to in [the Help Center page about Comments](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Perhaps it would be wise to remove any code that is not critical for review.

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ as you've correctly observed, I hit the character limit. I didn't want to delete those points altogether so I moved them in the comment section. I don't see which parts of the code are disposable. I could remove the tests, but each of them, in my view, provides a greater value than all of my bullet points combined

Comment: In `class JWT`, a 192-bit private `KEY` does not belong checked in to source control. Better to grab it from an env var, a vault, a file, something like that. // Also, nice tests!

Comment: @J_H thank you! Can you please explain what you mean by "belong checked in to source control"?

Comment: If you’re using the RCS revision control system to store source code, do not “ci” checkin edits containing secret keying material. If you’re using CVS, ClearCase, P4 perforce, SVN subversion, or git on GitHub, don’t make such secrets part of a commit.

Comment: @J_H but how would you run it if I didn't include a key (that is, the `JWT` class)?

Comment: I don't know spring and I'm proud, but out of curiosity I googled "spring authentication server" and got [this spring component](https://spring.io/projects/spring-authorization-server). Therefore **it seems** this post lacks some context how this code is related to the mentioned spring component: is it a replacement or an extension or something else? (again, I don't know spring, so it is possible, that for spring users everything is clear: please ignore my comment in such case).

Comment: Initialize KEY to null. Then fill in a value at runtime.

Answer (score 3):

My considerations:

1. You hash passwords (but a hacker could use a rainbow-table), so store only salted and hashed passwords having a (wild guess) 64-char-salt and a modern hash algorithm please.
2. You could reduce code by using `RestRepository` but `Repository`. This will bring eTag features and give correct http-status-codes.
3. You should `mvn spotbugs:check pmd:check findbugs:check`.
4. You can use `@Table("users")` instead of `@Table(name = "users")`.
5. Logging is your friend.
6. Have you heard about brute-force-attack prevention? The app **may** not Pentest-save.

Comment: OP is using bcrypt, although I also would recommend a more modern algorithm, such as Argon2id.

Comment: Yes, Argon2id + salt would be great!

Comment: Thank you! Though it's true I store hashed and salted passwords. I thought Bcrypt is the standard. It's Spring's default encoder

Comment: What is `RestRepository`? Can you share a link to the javadoc? I haven't found it

Comment: What do you mean by it may not be Pentest-safe? Why isn't it anyway?

Comment: Assuming your db-connection have a high pool limit of 1000. If 1000 requests are incomming due a DOS or DDOS attack every consequent request at the same time is not answered because the pool limit exceeded. You better send a 423 or 500 or 429 occour. Authentication may be a business critical system, a DDOS/DOS attack is between serious and business-critical.

Comment: @Sergey For RestRepository see here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest

Comment: @toolic Yes, my browser often translate considerations into conciderations. I dont know why. Happens very often.

Answer (score 3):

It might not be a concern when the live run environment is safe, if that's the case just skip following.

Store sensitive data in a vault, there are advantages, vaults are safe, just authorised actors have access to them, and decouples the developers from the burden of dealing with sensitive data.

There is a mix of two concerns, data access and security, in `User` entity that adds tight coupling between presentation layer and data access layer since security is a web concern. `UserDto` should implement `UserDetails` interface instead.

The global variables in test classes would be nice to have `private` access modifier.

One of the files listed by Docker section seems different than a Docker file. Additional details about following could be helpful.

```
version: '2.1'  
 
services:  
  token-service:  
    build:  
      context: .  
      dockerfile: Dockerfile  
    ports:  
      - "8100:8100"  
    depends_on:  
      db:  
        condition: service_healthy  
      eureka:  
        condition: service_healthy  
    environment:  
      POSTGRES_URL: jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/postgres  
      POSTGRES_USERNAME: postgres  
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres  
      EUREKA_URL: http://eureka:8761/eureka  
 
  db:  
    image: postgres  
    ports:  
      - "5432:5432"  
    environment:  
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres  
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres  
    healthcheck:  
      test: ["CMD", "pg_isready"]  
      interval: 10s  
      timeout: 10s  
      retries: 10  
 
  eureka:  
    image: nadchel/eureka-server:1.0  
    ports:  
      - "8761:8761"  
    healthcheck:  
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "curl -f http://eureka:8761"]  
      interval: 10s  
      timeout: 10s  
      retries: 10
```

Comment: Thank you! Can you please expand on the `User` issue? `UserDetails` is (actual) user information fetched from a DB, including their authorities, from which an authenticated `Authentication` is built. `UserDto`, on the other hand, is sign-up/log-in data provided by a user which, I believe, should *not* include authorities (and requires authentication)

Comment: That file you mentioned is a `docker-compose.yml` file. I added the caption